# Why is there an R^2 value (and what is determining it) when lm has no variance in the predicted value?

Tags: r, regression

Consider the following R code:

```
example <- function(n) {
    X <- 1:n
    Y <- rep(1,n)
    return(lm(Y~X))
}
#(2.13.0, i386-pc-mingw32)
summary(example(7))    #R^2 = .1963
summary(example(62))   #R^2 = .4529
summary(example(4540)) #R^2 = .7832
summary(example(104))) #R^2 = 0
#I did a search for n 6:10000, the result for R^2 is NaN for
#n = 2, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 2085 (not a typo), 4096, 6175 (not a typo), and 8340 (not a typo)
```

Looking at http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/appl/dqrls.f) did not help me understand what is going on, because I do not know Fortran.  In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245045/why-does-lm-return-values-when-there-is-no-variance-in-the-predicted-value) it was answered that floating point machine tolerance errors were are to blame for coefficients for X that are close to, but not quite 0.

$R^2$ is greater when the value for `coef(example(n))["X"]` is closer to 0. But...

1. Why is there an $R^2$ value at all?
2. What (specifically) is determining it?
3. Why the seemingly orderly progression of `NaN` results?
4. Why the violations of that progression?
5. What of this is 'expected' behavior?

Comment: Note:   7's R^2 should be 0.4542  to see something more constructive see my answer.  :-)

Comment: Well, to be fair, the user is supposed to actually *know* something about statistical methods before using tools (unlike, say, Excel users (ok, sorry about the cheap shot)).  Since it's rather obvious that R^2 approaches 1 as error approaches zero, we know better than to confuse a NaN value with the limit of a function.  Now, if there were a problem with R^2 diverging as ynoise-->0   (say, replace Y statement above with `Y <- rep(1,n)+runif(n)*ynoise` ), that would be interesting :-)

Comment: @eznme: I think the results are machine specific, or at least 32 or 64 bit specific; I have a 32-bit machine that gives 0.1963 for 7, but my 64-bit machine gives NaN.  Interestingly, on the 64-bit machine, the R^2s that are not NaN are all very close to 0.5. Makes sense when I think about it, but it surprised me at first.

Comment: +1 This is a fascinating question, especially with the curious progression of `NaN`s.

Comment: You're studying double precision rounding error.  Take a look at the coefficients; e.g., `apply(as.matrix(2:17), 1, function(n){example(n)$coefficients[-1]})`.  (My results, on a Win 7 x64 Xeon, range from -8e-17 to +3e-16; about half are true zeros.)  BTW, the Fortran source is of no help: it's just a wrapper for dqrdc; that's the code you want to look at.

Comment: I sort of object to the migration.  I know CrossValidated exists, but I specifically asked on StackOverflow because I wanted a more machine-level technical answer.

Comment: @drknexus  I slightly agree, but am rather ambivalent. The expertise on FP numerical computing is likely more numerous on SO; on CV there's a lot more expertise in the statistical side.  Either way, it's an R question, and Ben's comment below, about R Core, along with whuber's about Chambers' book, are likely the most insightful responses achievable on either site.  Only with these answers can we learn whether there are statistical or programming blunders.  It turns out that it's neither: it has more to do with numerical precision and the priorities of R core.

Comment: (Continued) But, as a user, the choice of CV is a better site, for the simple reason that diligent statistical analysis is the responsibility of the user, not the developer.  If the user sees an erroneous $R^2$ relative to the magnitude of the RSS, then they should do their own post-processing before reporting further.  Programming-wise, I'd like to know how to avoid these numerical issues as much as possible, but I think that they can't be escaped, and that's where it's important to have  a diligent user and to educate others.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, you got the same answer from me that you would have gotten on SO -- I was busy composing it when the question got migrated, and I had to save my work and paste it over here ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Ben Bolker says, the answer to this question can be found in the code for `summary.lm()`.

Here's the header:

```
function (object, correlation = FALSE, symbolic.cor = FALSE, 
    ...) 
{
```

So, let `x <- 1:1000; y <- rep(1,1000); z <- lm(y ~ x)` and then take a look at this slightly modified extract:

```
    p <- z$rank
    rdf <- z$df.residual
    Qr <- stats:::qr.lm(z)
    n <- NROW(Qr$qr)
    r <- z$residuals
    f <- z$fitted.values
    w <- z$weights
    if (is.null(w)) {
        mss <- sum((f - mean(f))^2)
        rss <- sum(r^2)
    }
    ans <- z[c("call", "terms")]
    if (p != attr(z$terms, "intercept")) {
        df.int <- 1L
        ans$r.squared <- mss/(mss + rss)
        ans$adj.r.squared <- 1 - (1 - ans$r.squared) * ((n - 
            df.int)/rdf)
    }
```

Notice that ans\$r.squared is $0.4998923$...

To answer a question with a question: what do we draw from this?  :)

I believe the answer lies in how R handles floating point numbers.  I think that `mss` and `rss` are the sums of very small (squared) rounding errors, hence the reason $R^2$ is about 0.5.  As for the progression, I suspect this has to do with the number of values that it takes for the +/- approximations to cancel out to 0 (for both `mss` and `rss`, as `0/0` is likely the source of these `NaN` values).  I don't know why the values differ from a `2^(1:k)` progression, though.

---

Update 1: [Here is a nice thread from R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2000-February/010105.html) addressing some of the reasons that underflow warnings are not addressed in R.

In addition, [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802592/dealing-with-very-small-numbers-in-r) has a number of interesting posts and useful links regarding underflow, higher precision arithmetic, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I'm curious about your motivation for asking the question. I can't think of a **practical** reason this behavior should matter; intellectual curiosity is an alternative (and IMO much more sensible) reason. I think you don't need to understand FORTRAN to answer this question, but I think you do need to know about QR decomposition and its use in linear regression.  If you treat `dqrls` as a black box that computes a QR decomposition and returns various information about it, then you may be able to trace the steps ... or just go straight to `summary.lm` and trace through to see how the R^2 is calculated.  In particular:

```
mss <- if (attr(z$terms, "intercept")) 
          sum((f - mean(f))^2)
       else sum(f^2)
rss <- sum(r^2)
## ... stuff ...
ans$r.squared <- mss/(mss + rss)
```

Then you have to go back into `lm.fit` and see that the fitted values are computed as `r1 <- y - z$residuals` (i.e. as the response minus the residuals).  Now you can go figure out what determines the value of the residuals and whether the value minus its mean is exactly zero or not, and from there figure out the computational outcomes ...

Comment: Intellectual curiosity is the majority of the reason for my question.  A colleague reported the behavior and I wanted to poke around and see if I could figure it out.  After I traced the issue beyond my skill-set, I decided to ask the question.  As a practical issue, sometimes analyses are done by batch, or other errors occur, and this behavior strikes me as decidedly 'odd'.

Comment: mms and rss are both results of z, which is the name of the lm object inside of summary.lm.  So, an answer probably does require an explanation of QR decomposition, its use in linear regression, and specifically some details QR decomposition as instantiated in the code underlying R in order to explain why the QR decomposition ends up with approximations of 0 rather than 0 itself.

Comment: @drknexus I disagree. QR decomp is one of many numerical algorithms; if the underlying issue is numerical precision, this'll crop up in QR, matrix multiplication, non-linear solvers, and so many other places. The essential sequence is simple: the coefficients are very slightly off (should be (0,1)); this isn't unreasonable, yet produces the `mss` and `rss` "noise". It's the GIGO principle that assures that $R^2$ is precise, but incorrect.  I'd rather insert a "garbage detector" before calculating $R^2$ than to modify the QR algo, because I doubt its validity could be improved.

Comment: It seems to me that the garbage detector should be at the QR or right before it.  A simple sanity check on the variance of Y and warning that Y lacks variance would be fine (I may write an lm wrapper for my friends that does just this).  It seems to me that by the time you are calculating $R^2$, one is already too far down the computational rabbit hole to know if one is looking at garbage or not.

Answer (score 0):

$R^2$ is defined as   $R^2 = 1-\frac{\textrm{SS}_{err}}{\textrm{SS}_{tot}}$   ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_squared ), so if the sum-of-squares-total is 0 then it is undefined. In my opinion R should show an error-message.

Comment: Can you give a practical situation where this behavior would matter?

Comment: @BenBolker I can: Model selection based on a model with highest R-squared.  :)

Comment: @Iterator I can't see how that would matter? OtherR2 >< NaN would always return NA which would a) break your code anyways or b) force you to account for and ignore it.

Comment: @Brandon -- Iterator put the smiley in there and you *still* got whooshed!

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen  Hehe...  I address `NA`s over on StackOverflow.  ;-)  At least that's been my impetus for several recent questions - breaking my code doesn't happen often enough in some cases, and accounting for NAs: bring it on!  :)

Comment: @BenBolker Yea with real data this doesn't happen (not after the symmetry-break after the big-bang). How about my idea that R should show an error instead of just silently giving bogus-result? Would help in those situations when you accidentally did something to your data that made it have zero variance

Comment: @eznme  While an error is good, it is quite difficult to catch all kinds of places where floating point issues arise, notably in the world of IEEE-754 arithmetic.  The lesson here is that even the bread and butter calculations with R should be handled delicately.

Comment: These considerations are especially important because in his writings, John Chambers (one of the originators of S and therefore a "grandfather" of R) strongly emphasizes the use of R for *reliable computing.*  E.g., see Chambers, *Software for Data Analysis: Programming with R* (Springer Verlag 2008): "the computations and the software for data analysis should be trustworthy: they should do what they claim, and be seen to do so."  [At p. 3.]

Comment: @Iterator Of course i cannot check for float-equality (nor can we check whether R^2 is too small because what is "too small"), but what i would like is writing R^2=NaN instead of silently having undefined behavior.

Comment: ... to do that, we would have to modify `summary` to look at if it's input is bitwise identical. This would catch the cases in which un-initialized/zero'ed data is accidentally used (e.g. previous assignment to wrong variable...) even if it was linearily transformed; cool.

Comment: The problem is that for better or worse, R-core is resistant to (as they see it) festooning the code with many, many checks that intercept all corner cases and possible weird user errors -- they are afraid (I think) that it will (a) take huge amounts of their time, (b) make the code base much larger and harder to read (because there are literally thousands of these special cases), and (c) slow down execution by forcing such checks all the time even in situations where computations are being repeated many, many times.

Comment: @BenBolker (a)-(c) all true.

Comment: @eznme In order to get the output, one has to detect possible underflow issues.  This is often, but not always, feasible.  In a simple case like this, I think that there should be an underflow check.  It's a ratio of two floats, which is an operation that's not a big part of the computational cost of the summary.  I don't excuse not checking, but, as Ben points out, it'll take some time and effort to get these checks inserted in lots of places.